# Why is a function defined in a .h file redefined in a .c file?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am reading through Linux v3.19's implementation of PID namespaces and in `pid_namespace.h` there are functions defined that are redefined in `pid_namespace.c`. For example, in [`pid_namespace.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.19.8/source/include/linux/pid_namespace.h#L76) there is the following definition:

```
static inline struct pid_namespace *copy_pid_ns(unsigned long flags,
    struct user_namespace *user_ns, struct pid_namespace *ns)
{
    if (flags & CLONE_NEWPID)
        ns = ERR_PTR(-EINVAL);
    return ns;
}
```

And then in [`pid_namespace.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.19.8/source/kernel/pid_namespace.c#L153) there is a second `copy_pid_ns` definition:

```
struct pid_namespace *copy_pid_ns(unsigned long flags,
    struct user_namespace *user_ns, struct pid_namespace *old_ns)
{
    if (!(flags & CLONE_NEWPID))
        return get_pid_ns(old_ns);
    if (task_active_pid_ns(current) != old_ns)
        return ERR_PTR(-EINVAL);
    return create_pid_namespace(user_ns, old_ns);
}
```

What does this re-defining achieve? Why is it done? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Note

The question omits relevant information from the source code repository it extracted the source code from, so the answer below does not apply to the source code in those files. It appears at most one of the two definitions is selected based on build options, so they are not both used in the same build.

### Old Answer Regarding `static inline`

The version in the header is marked `static inline`. In this declaration, `static` causes the name `copy_pid_ns` to have *internal linkage*, meaning the definition here will apply only to uses of `copy_pid_ns` in the current translation unit (the source file being compiled, including the files it includes). The idea of `inline` is that this function is so small, it would be good if, wherever it is called, the compiler just wrote the code for it in place of the call instead of actually using a subroutine call instruction for the function. (Technically `inline` is just a suggestion to the compiler in this regard. Good modern compilers mostly make their own decisions about which functions to inline.)

Because the definition in the header is `static inline`, it is not accessible to other translation units. The definition in the other source file has *external linkage*, meaning any uses of `copy_pid_ns` in other translation units can be linked to it (if they do not have their own private `static` version). Those uses in other translation units will have to use actual subroutine call instructions to call this function.

Providing an external version is not necessary if all uses of `copy_pid_ns` have the static version available, but one may be provided because that is not always the case or just as a safety fallback.

Comment: @0andriy: Then the question needs to be updated to show the relevant code from the files. Links to external pages are supposed to be supplemental on Stack Overflow, not an integral part of a question or answer. As the question stands, it is answered as posed. If it is changed, I will delete or edit this answer. Or we can close the question as lacking in details.

Comment: @0andriy: What point? I answered the question **as asked**. Contributors to Stack Overflow are not expected to rummage through files elsewhere for additional information.

Comment: @0andriy: I am not interested in Stack Overflow reputation or other imaginary Internet points, and it is improper for you to impugn the motives of others. I contribute to share information. That sometimes involves things that are overlooked or mistaken, as all human activity is subject to error. But you have no grounds to make accusations of ill intent.

Answer (score 4):

These two definitions corresponds to two **incompatible configurations**:

1. Definition of `copy_pid_ns` in the `include/linux/pid_namespace.h#L76` header is parsed only with `CONFIG_PID_NS` option **disabled** (see line 68 in that header).
2. The file `kernel/pid_namespace.c` is compiled only with `CONFIG_PID_NS` option **enabled** (it can be found from `kernel/Makefile`). For that configuration the header contains just a declaration of the function at line 62.

Situation when the header file declares some function twice is quite natural for the Linux kernel sources:

1. One **declaration** (without **definition**) corresponds to some functionality being enabled. In that configuration the function is **defined** in some source file which is compiled only with functionality being enabled.
2. Another **declaration** is a **definition** of `static inline` function and corresponds to disabled functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a redefinition. The key to realizing what's intended here is the presence of `static` qualifier for the first definition, and knowing how programs are built with C. Also, `inline` is seldom used without `static`, at least with C89 and GNU extensions which is what is used to compile Linux, but `inline` in and out of itself doesn't play a role here.

The `static inline` definition in `pid_namespace.h` is only visible to the translation unit (.c file) that includes that header file, directly or indirectly. The `static` qualifier is what restricts this visibility. If you include `pid_namespace.h` from another translation unit, that translation unit will have its own, another copy of the function. Each object file will have its own copy of the function definition, available only to itself. Additionally, because of the `inline` qualifier, the function may not even exist as such because the compiler [is free to "inline" it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html).

The second definition does not have a `static` qualifier and can thus be used by other translation units that do not themselves contain it. The C compiler compiles object files from their respective translation units, and the linker links these object files together and produces a program image where references to said definition are correctly resolved. The compiler does not care if more than one translation unit embed the same function -- to it they're just object files it needs to compile one by one. But the linker will abort because it isn't designed to have to choose between such multiple definitions in its input.

In practice, there is many ways this can be used. The former definition may be the short version used in kernel mode (privileged kernel code), while the latter is used in user mode, as result of processing a system call, for example.

In general, defining procedures several times is permitted as long as there is at most one object available to the linker (in case it needs to resolve references to the function, like function calls). You can juggle your .c and .h files however you like, as long as that requirement holds. If you also know how to use `static` and `inline` qualifiers, you can add definitions that are not externally visible (`static`) and benefit from compiler being able to inline them.

Comment: There are some technicalities in the C standard that may be hard to word well in answering questions like this. The `static` keyword does not cause the identifier to be visible only in the translation unit, because **all** identifiers are only visible in, at most, the translation unit in which they are declared. What `static` affects here is *linkage*, which is a process in which two an identifier declared in different scopes or more than once in the same scope can be made to refer to the same object or function.

Comment: Indeed. How do you proposes I improve my wording? I was trying to express how "visible only in the translation unit" means there is an object in the object file but you can't use it for links across object files, only within the object file where it is embedded.

Comment: I do not have a specific proposal for improving the word—I recognize it is difficult to convey several new concepts to readers while trying to be correct and not too hard to read. In this case, I just wanted people to be aware of the issues and think about how to convey such issues. Styles and approaches to communicating develop over time and experience.

Answer (score 0):

First look at qualifiers in front of the function:

1. static inline... -> **static** will be resolved only in included source files (*.c, *.cpp)
   like private qualifier, **inline** will replace directly this function instead accessing it as reference
2. have no qualifiers -> more like a public external function. If you define your usage of the function as **extern** you should compile (*.c) file which contains implementation of the function and then the linker will resolve your call to the function as reference.